# How can I reference an anonymous json array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a large JSON object which is being returned from QuickBooks Online API. It is valid JSON and shows up on the console (after logging it).

Upon inspecting the console, I see the following:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Which can be expanded to:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
11: Object
12: Object
13: Object
14: Object
15: Object
16: Object
17: Object
18: Object
19: Object
20: Object
21: Object
22: Object
23: Object
24: Object
length: 25
__proto__: Array[0]
```

`0: Object` expands to:

```
0: Object
*_data: Object
$$hashKey: "object:82"
__proto__: Object
```

`*_data: Object` expands to:

```
Active: Array[1]
Balance: Array[1]
BalanceWithJobs: Array[1]
BillAddr: Array[1]
BillWithParent: Array[1]
DisplayName: Array[1]
FamilyName: Array[1]
Fax: Array[1]
FullyQualifiedName: Array[1]
GivenName: Array[1]
Id: Array[1]
Job: Array[1]
MetaData: Array[1]
Mobile: Array[1]
PreferredDeliveryMethod: Array[1]
PrimaryEmailAddr: Array[1]
PrimaryPhone: Array[1]
PrintOnCheckName: Array[1]
SalesTermRef: Array[1]
SyncToken: Array[1]
Taxable: Array[1]
```

I'm trying to access a property called `DisplayName`.

The Angular code that is being used to console.log the json data:

```
$http.get('/customer').success(function(customers) {
    $scope.customers = customers;
    console.log($scope.customers[0]["*_data"].DisplayName[0]);
});
```

How can this be done? Can something be typed in the console to return its value?

**Update:**

I can access the object using:

`console.log($scope.customers[0]);`

However, `*_data` is an object.  I was thinking something like:

`console.log($scope.customers[0].*_data);` would work however, I receive the error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *`.

Comment: Can you do it with bracket notation? like `<thisjson>[0]["*_data"]["DisplayName"];` ?

Comment: @brbcoding, I receive this error when trying: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`  And without the brackets, `thisjson` is not defined.

Comment: brbcoding didn't mean for `<thisjson>` to be used literally, just as a placeholder for whatever variable you store the json in.

Comment: RaphaelRafatpanah what @chazsolo said.

Comment: Ahh.  `console.log($scope.customers[0]);` returns an `object` in the console.  How can I access an object?  `console.log($scope.customers[0]["*_data"]);` returns undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you logging it to the console?

Assuming you are, and that you have something like:

```
console.log(data);
```

You can access the data like this:

```
data[0]["*_data"].DisplayName[0]
```

That is:

1. Dereference the first array item with `data[0]`
2. Then access the `*_data` property. Because its name is not a valid property name, you have to use the `["string"]` form.
3. The `DisplayName` value is an array. Take the first value with `[0]`.

---

#### EDIT

Ok, wow this was actually quite an interesting one!

It seems that the response data contains a strange character which makes it tricky to access the response. Specifically:

```
> Object.keys($scope.customers[0])[0]
"*_data"
> Object.keys($scope.customers[0])[0] == "*_data"
false
```

Huh? Why aren't they equal? One of those characters must be a unicode char which looks identical but has a different value!

Anyway it's easy enough to work around this:

```
var mysteriousKey = Object.keys($scope.customers[0])[0];
var data = $scope.customers[0][mysteriousKey];
```

This gives me:

> Object {Id: Array[1], SyncToken: Array[1], MetaData: Array[1], GivenName: Array[1], FamilyName: Array[1]…}

Which I think it what you were after.

Comment: When trying, I receive `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`.  It is being logged to the console.

Comment: Who logs it to the console? Is it your code that's making this request of the QuickBooks API?

Comment: Yes. I have an angular $http.get() request to my backend, which returns the json data.  I immediately logged that data to the console.  I also tried doing something this: `console.log($scope.customers[0]["*_data"].DisplayName[0]);` however, the console returns this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'DisplayName' of undefined`

Comment: Then you're getting close. I suggest you set a breakpoint there and inspect the data you're getting back. There's no way I can really help you from here. Perhaps the property name is `_data` instead of `*_data`?

Comment: Thank you. I do receive the right object when running `console.log($scope.customers[0]);` which returns `Object {*_data: Object}*_data: Object__proto__: Object` Perhaps the problem is because "*_data" is an object and not an array?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the issue here is. Can you post a screenshot of the object as displayed by the debugger in Chrome's devtools?

Comment: I think the `*`is a red herring. Perhaps it's being added in the console. Try this: `data[0]._data.DisplayName`

Comment: `console.log($scope.customers[0]._data);` returns 'undefined.'  You can view the console.log yourself at persianturtle.com/app.  I've reset it so it logs `$scope.customers`.

Comment: Seeing it for myself was useful. I've made an edit which includes a fix. This was an interesting one!

Answer (score 1):

Your array should be assigned to a variable. Reference the index of the item in the array you want, and access it's `DisplayName` property (which is also an array).

```
var objArray; // this has your array of objects
objArray[0]["*_data"].DisplayName[0]; // should be the value you are looking for.
```

Comment: What if `*_data` is an object?  How can it be referenced?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah `*_data` even as an object would be referenced this way. It's referred to as square bracket notation as oppose to dot notation. Because this property has an `*`, you'll want to use the square bracket notation. However, if you property was for example `_data` you could do `objArray[0]._data` or `objArray[0]["_data"]`. Both produce the same result. For special characters like the asterisk though, it's better to use square bracket notation to avoid parser errors.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation.  The reason it wasn't working was because of the * looked like an asterix but actually had a different value internally.  See the chosen answer for details. Thanks again.